# Any way to improve accuracy of getCurrentPosition() coordinates other than enableHighAccuracy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

My intention is to utilize the coordinates that are returned by geolocation in order to generate directions to a given destination, without the visitor having to manually input their address. However, since these coordinates seem to vary from browser to browser, whereby some sets are accurate and other sets are not accurate at all, I am beginning to think this will be impossible.

The code below apparently has very little impact on the accuracy of the returned values.

```
    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: Infinity,
        maximumAge: 0
    };
```

Is there another way to improve the accuracy of the coordinates, so that the coordinates actually become usable?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Official Google Documentation, the Google Maps Geolocation API returns a location and accuracy radius based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client can detect. The protocol used to send this data to the server and to return a response to the client. 
In Geolocation request, you must specify a key in your request. The request body must be formatted as JSON.

You may include '*radioType*' in the API call. The mobile radio type supports '*lte, gsm, cdma, and wcdma*'. While this field is optional, it should be included if a value is available, for more accurate results.

For more details regarding Maps Geocoding API, please follow this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: if i post my code, can you tell me what's wrong it?? i'm getting accurate readings on Microsoft Edge, inaccurate readings in Mozilla Firefox, and no readings at all in Google Chrome.

Comment: sure mate, just edit your post and let see how we can help you.

Comment: i'm actually not working on that project anymore, but i am indeed working on a new project that will require accurate geo coordinates. however, i just reread the documentation, so if i still can't figure it out myself when i get to that point, i'll message you! thanks a lot for taking the time to respond

Comment: i could really use your help now!! i have an array of geocoordinates, and--before dropping markers for every geocoordinate on the map--i want to check to see if the marker is first within the map bounds; if the coordinates are within the bounds, then i will drop the marker, and if not i won't. my code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928046/if-containsarrayoflatlngobjectsi-producing-typeerror-a-lat-is-not/39928120?noredirect=1#comment67139618_39928120 please thumb it up too if you don't mind <3 :]